# How to make interdependent edittexts change each others value programmatically with TextWatcher

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I am programatically creating a variable number of EditTexts based on user input, and each `EditText` is paired with another (so I'm creating twice as many as the user asks for). When the user changes the value in one, I want the matching paired `EditText` to also be changed.

I have a loop that goes through an array with all of the editTexts and creates a `TextWatcher` for each, but when I try to change texts in the `onTextChanged` method the program crashes.

```
for(int i = 0; i < waysToSplit; i++)
{
    editTexts[i] = new EditText(this);
    editTexts[i+waysToSplit] = new EditText(this); //The paired edittext
    editTexts[i].setId(i+1);
    editTexts[i].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                //Change the paired box
                editTexts[i+waysToSplit].setText("changed");

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
            }
 }
```

Not only will it not let me use the variable i inside of the onTextChanged method ("Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method") but even if for testing purposes I try to make a specific box change with something like
    `editTexts[3].setText("Changed");`
nothing is happening.

Hopefully that is enough code to understand what is going on..Any help much appreciated. The closest I could find was [Android: Two EditTexts dependent on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717210/android-two-edittexts-dependent-on-each-other) but there isn't any code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pull your paired `EditText` out into a separate declaration. You can then mark it `final` and gain access to it in your listener.

```
for(int i = 0; i < waysToSplit; i++)
{
    editTexts[i] = new EditText(context);
    final EditText paired = new EditText(context);//The paired edittext
    editTexts[i+waysToSplit] = paired;
    editTexts[i].setId(i+1);
    editTexts[i].addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //Change the paired box
                paired.setText("changed");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
            }
    });
}
```